# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xx-xx.s3.amazonaws.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to implemet react fineuploader direct upload to s3 bucket.I get this error when i try to upload files.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xx-xx.s3.amazonaws.com/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://x.x.com' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 403.

In my local i can write to s3 using cors-anywhere
if i append it before xx-xx.s3.amazonaws.com

I am using react+node+express and Django as backend.

Comment: Take a look at [Mozilla's guide to cross-origin requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 0):

If the target server doesn't allow cross-origin requests then you will have to proxy those requests by your own backend, which is a good practice anyway because those requests will likely need to contain some API keys or other credentials that should never be stored on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the aws console to allow any domain and saved then i changed it back to just my domain and it worked.